# Angular Testing: Cannot read property 'images' of undefined

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I am trying to run karma tests on an Angular component called `AlbumInfoComponent`. In this component, I have a function named `getStyles()` that does the following:

```
  getStyles() {
    return {
      "background-image":'url('+this.data.images[1].url+')'
    }
  }
```

it uses a variable called `data` initialized as: `private user: {} = {}`

I have a test that runs only the default `should create` test only. Though for some reason when running the test, I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'images' of undefined`. My initial thought is that since Angular doesn't know there is a value in data called `images`, it will fail. Because of that, I tried setting component equal to a mock component data. Here is my testing code:

```
describe('AlbumInfoComponent', () => {
  let component: AlbumInfoComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AlbumInfoComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ LandingComponent, FaIconComponent, HomeComponent, LoginComponent, AlbumInfoComponent, RecentReleasesComponent, QueueComponent, SearchComponent, TitleComponent, UserComponent, SearchBarComponent, RecentReleaseComponent, YourQueueComponent    ],
      imports: [FormsModule, HttpClientTestingModule,         RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([]), MatSnackBarModule    ],
      providers: [InfoService, HttpClient, TokenService ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AlbumInfoComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
  it('should create', () => {    
    component.data = {
      "images": [
      {
        "height": 640,
        "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b273626d2ce1fb80955645d4d787",
        "width": 640
      },
      {
        "height": 300,
        "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d00001e02626d2ce1fb80955645d4d787",
        "width": 300
      },
      {
        "height": 64,
        "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d00004851626d2ce1fb80955645d4d787",
        "width": 64
      }
      ]
    }
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Is there a way to force the data variable to be equal to the mock data to fix the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer worked: https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/1546#issuecomment-461945741

We need to destroy the fixture after each test. so do this:

```
  afterEach(() => {
    fixture.destroy();
  });
```